# Relation between a.s. and L_{2} convergence

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm working through a proof, where I need to establish that $X_{t}\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}0$. All I know is that $\left|X_{t}\right|\leq\left|Y_{n}\right|+\left|Z_{n}\right|$ for $t\in[n,n+1)$, where $\left|Z_{n}\right|\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}0$ and $\left|Y_{n}\right|\overset{L_{2}}{\longrightarrow}0$. Hence there is a subsequence s.t. $\left|Y_{n_{k}}\right|\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}0$. But how can we go from there to $X_{t}\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}0$? I'm completely lost.

So, I need that for any $\varepsilon>0$
  $\exists N$
  s.t. $\left|X_{t}\right|<\varepsilon$
  for all $t>N$ a.s.
 . But since I only have $\left|Y_{n_{k}}\right|\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}0$
  along the subsequence $(n_{k})_{k\geq\mathbb{N}}$
 , there may be intervals $[m,m+1]$
  arbitrarily far out, where I cannot necessarily control $X_{t}$
  for $t\in[m,m+1]$
  (for $m\notin\left\{ n_{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ 
 ).

Comment: Do you just need $X_{t}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely when $t\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Yes, for $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Maybe I am stupid, but if $|Y_{n}|\rightarrow 0$ in $L^{2}$ sense, does not this imply $|Y_{n}|\rightarrow 0$ pointwise minus a measure zero set? Since we are working with space of finite measure, a measurable function that does not vanish on a subset of positive measure should have positive $L^{2}$-norm.

Comment: At least in general, $L_{2}$-convergence only implies almost sure convergence (i.e. pointwise minus a measure zero set) along a subsequence.

Comment: I think this is true in general, but in finite measure case you should have $L^{1}\subset L^{2}\cdots \subset L^{\infty}$. So convergence in $L^{2}$ should imply convergence in $L^{\infty}$ as well. And that is almost sure convergence.

Comment: It seems like you are missing some essential part of the proof that makes this statement true. If you took $Z_n \equiv 0$ and $Y_n$ to be the "dancing" counterexample ($L_2$ but not a.s. convergence), with $X_t = Y_{\lfloor t \rfloor}$ you'd have a counterexample.

Comment: @Bombyxmori No (emphatically). Simple counterexample: $$f_{k+2^n}=\mathbf 1_{[k/2^n,(k+1)/2^n]},$$ for every integers $n\geqslant0$ and $0\leqslant k\lt2^n$, on $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Did: I see. I knew I must be confused with something, so I ask. Thanks!

Comment: @Bombyxmori - you've got the reverse. If you have convergence in r-th mean, then you have convergence in s-th mean for $r>s\geq 1$, i.e. $E[|X_n - X|^r] \to 0 \implies E[|X_n-X|^s] \to 0$.

Comment: @Batman: Yeah, I realized this when I reviewed how I applied Holder. Obviously I have $L^{2}\subset L^{1}$, etc. You are definitely right.